# Why doesn't if ("T") throw an error even though "T" is not a logical vector?

Tags: r

I stumbled upon this when I tried to find out why some function I wrote gave unexpected output.

```
> if ("T") print("why?")
[1] "why?"
```

Why does this work instead of giving out an `argument is not interpretable as logical` error? That is what happens to every other string passed to `if`, except `"T", "F", "TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`.

According to the help page of `if`, the condition inside the brackets must be a logical vector, but

```
> is.logical("T")
[1] FALSE
```

How does that go together? How does `if` evaluate the condition, is there anything happening secretly that converts "T" to T?

Comment: The docs say that the condition is coerced to logical, if possible.

Comment: as far as I can tell, the docs https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#if don't mention coercing using `as.logical`

Comment: @SamMason The standard docs mention the coercion, although they don’t mention as.logical directly it’s reasonable to presume the same sorts of rules apply. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html

Comment: @joran huh, thought I looked there, not sure why I didn't notice it!  using `as.logical` indeed makes sense

Comment: @SamMason It's easy to miss stuff. It probably would be slightly more clear if they explicitly referenced the special coercion cases mentioned in `?as.logical`.

Comment: You might be interested in function `isTRUE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `as.logical` converts a limited number of strings to logical:

> as.logical attempts to coerce its argument to be of logical type. For
>   factors, this uses the levels (labels). Like as.vector it strips
>   attributes including names. Character strings c("T", "TRUE", "True",
>   "true") are regarded as true, c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false") as
>   false, and all others as NA.

The help file for `if` states that coercion takes place, but not how:

> Other types are coerced to logical if possible, ignoring any class.

Comment: I feel like it would be a good idea to include in your answer that *Other types are coerced to logical if possible, ignoring any class.* (from `help("if")`, the `cond` argument).  It may not be known to OP, and is definitely not obvious since `if` is primitive.